# Postgresql trigger which execute update query only one time for statemnt

Tags: postgresql

I use PostgreSQL 11.8 and faced task, when I need use trigger. Main goal - when set or update some row from table products, after execute UPDATE or INXERT I need set `created_at` data for all exist rows in table `products` which has the same `group_identity`. I cretaed this trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maint_sales_summary_bytime() RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $maint_sales_summary_bytime$
    DECLARE
        delta_time_key          timestamp;
        delta_group_identity   varchar;

    BEGIN



        IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN

            delta_time_key = NEW.created_at;
            delta_group_identity = NEW.group_identity;

        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN

            delta_time_key = NEW.created_at;
            delta_group_identity = NEW.group_identity;

        END IF;

                UPDATE products
                SET 
                created_at = delta_time_key
                WHERE group_identity = delta_group_identity;    

        RETURN NULL;

    END;
$maint_sales_summary_bytime$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER maint_sales_summary_bytime
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON products
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE maint_sales_summary_bytime();
```

But when I try to execute it

```
UPDATE products
SET name = 'hello test1'
WHERE id = 131545
```

I faced with with 78 seconds spent time and error

```
UPDATE products
    SET name = 'hello test1'
    WHERE id = 131545
> ERROR:  stack depth limit exceeded
  HINT:  Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate.
  CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "public"."brand" x WHERE "id" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 FOR KEY SHARE OF x"
  SQL statement "UPDATE products
                  SET 
                                    created_at = delta_time_key
                  WHERE group_identity = delta_group_identity"
  PL/pgSQL function maint_sales_summary_bytime() line 23 at SQL statement
  SQL statement "UPDATE products
                  SET 
                                    created_at = delta_time_key
                  WHERE group_identity = delta_group_identity"
  PL/pgSQL function maint_sales_summary_bytime() line 23 at SQL statement
  SQL statement "UPDATE products
                  SET 
                                    created_at = delta_time_key
                  WHERE group_identity = delta_group_identity"
  PL/pgSQL function maint_sales_summary_bytime() line 23 at SQL statement
  SQL statement "UPDATE products
                  SET 
                                    created_at = delta_time_key
                  WHERE group_identity = delta_group_identity"
  PL/pgSQL function maint_sales_summary_bytime() line 23 at SQL statement
  SQL statement "UPDATE products
                  SET 
                                    created_at = delta_time_key
                  WHERE group_identity = delta_group_identity"
  PL/pgSQL function maint_sales_summary_bytime() line 23 at SQL statement
  SQL statement "UPDATE products
                  SET 
                                    created_at = delta_time_key
                  WHERE group_identity = delta_group_identity"
  PL/pgSQL function maint_sales_summary_bytime() line 23 at SQL statement
  SQL statement "UPDATE products
                  SET 
                                    created_at = delta_time_key
                  WHERE group_identity = delta_group_identity"
  PL/pgSQL function maint_sales_summary_bytime() line 23 at SQL statement
  SQL statement "UPDATE products
                  SET 
                                    created_at = delta_time_key
                  WHERE group_identity = delta_group_identity"
  PL/pgSQL function maint_sales_summary_bytime() line 23 at SQL statement
  SQL statement "UPDATE products
                  SET 
                                    created_at = delta_time_key
                  WHERE group_identity = delta_group_identity"
  PL/pgSQL function maint_sales_summary_bytime() line 23 at SQL statement
  SQL statement "UPDATE products
                  SET 
                                    created_at = delta_time_key
                  WHERE group_identity = delta_group_identity"
  PL/pgSQL function maint_sales_summary_bytime() line 23 at SQL statement
  SQL statement "UPDATE products
                  SET 
                                    created_at = delta_time_key
                  WHERE group_identity = delta_group_identity"
  PL/pgSQL function maint_sales_summary_bytime() line 23 at SQL statement
  SQL statement "UPDATE products
                  SET 
                                    created_at = delta_time_key
                  WHERE group_identity = delta_group_identity"
  PL/pgSQL function maint_sales_summary_bytime() line 23 at SQL statement
  SQL statement "UPDATE products
                  SET 
                                    created_at = delta_time_key
                  WHERE group_identity = delta_group_identity"
  PL/pgSQL function maint_sales_summary_bytime() line 23 at SQL statement
  SQL statement "UPDATE products
                  SET 
                                    created_at = delta_time_key
                  WHERE group_identity = delta_group_identity"
  PL/pgSQL function maint_sales_summary_bytime() line 23 at SQL statement
  SQL statement "UPDATE products
                  SET 
                                    created_at = delta_time_key
                  WHERE group_identity = delta_group_identity"
  PL/pgSQL function maint_sales_summary_bytime() line 23 at SQL statement
  SQL statement "UPDATE products
                  SET 
                                    created_at = delta_time_key
                  WHERE group_identity = delta_group_identity"
  PL/pgSQL function main
> Time: 86.868s
```

look like trigger try to execute this query for each row from `products`, but I need execute this trigger only one time after statment INSERT or UPDATE was executed ro ONE row

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `IF` statement at the beginning seems useless as both branches do exactly the same thing. There is also no need for the variables anyway, as you can refer to the `new` record inside the UPDATE statement as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trigger is a recursive trigger.

You could try to disable recursivity with:

```
CREATE TRIGGER maint_sales_summary_bytime
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON products
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() = 0)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE maint_sales_summary_bytime();
```

See [pg_trigger_depth()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html).

Comment: `CREATE TRIGGER maint_sales_summary_bytime
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON products
    WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() = 0)
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE maint_sales_summary_bytime();` I faced with `)
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FOR"
  LINE 4:     FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE maint_sales_summary_bytim..`

Comment: `CREATE TRIGGER maint_sales_summary_bytime
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON products
        FOR EACH ROW 
  WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() = 0)
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE maint_sales_summary_bytime();` works like a charm, thank you

Comment: OK I have fixed my answer.